# Convert int to datetime with first of January as the day and month

Tags: sql, datetime

I have int column in a table and I need to insert this column in another column in the same table but with datetime format, and the day and month will be the first day of the year which is stand in the first column, I wrote the followings query:

```
begin transaction
update Table_1 set col2=CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),col2))
where  conditions.....
rollback;
```

I got the followings error :

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 23
>  The conversion of a varchar
> data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The statement has been terminated.

did any one know how to fix this issue.

I try to insert datetime in one column from another column in the same table

Comment: What does the int column represent? Is it the year? eg. 01/01/[intvalue] ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? CONVERT is a product specific function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause for this error, one of the data in the first column have illegal value and it is not allowed to converted to date format.

Comment: And I assume you from now on always will use proper data types!